# UIImagePicker shows black space at bottom after dismissing it

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-sdk-3.0

Opening an `UIImagePicker` to pick an `image` from `library`/`camera`, after dismiss `Window` shrinks in size by leaving extra blank space at bottom.  It reduced the size of window, it continuously being there while moving to other screens.

Anyone having an idea why it's happening. Please check below images. Same think happens in `device` too.

It's just a general code I've kept, still here it is.

```
let imagePicker=UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Can you try debugging view hierarchy in Xcode?

Comment: Do you have details about the view in your screenshot? Is the entire view a `UIImageView`? What is it's content mode? Does this screen use auto layout, and if so, what constraints? And could the issue have anything to do with the *difference* in the two screenshots? (Lower right red button.)

Comment: I thought it might have been generic issue. But I got a point to solve it, Unfortunately ViewController's 'Under bottom bar' property kept false by some reason, which should be true. I was hiding tabbar manually when coming to this view, whereas after hiding, it laid out perfectly. But when UIImagePicker presented and dismissed, it detected that property is false and it has to decrease the view size.